# Solr multilingual stemisation

Tags: solr, multilingual

I'm using Solr to index documents like .pdf or .docx. These documents are in french or in english and I want to use the stemisation for both languages.

For exemple, if I search "chevaux" I want to find "cheval" (french) and if I search "raise" I want to find "raising" (english).
Is there a way to do this without createting 2 core (one in english and one in french) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two fields, one with the field definition you want for French, and one with the field definition you want for English. Then use [the Language Detection](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/detecting-languages-during-indexing.html) feature to submit the content to the correct field.

When searching, query the field that has the correct language as the user, or if you don't know, search both - or use language detection to try to do a better guess.

You can also index the same content into both fields, but my initial guess is that it'll give you weird results down the road, where someone enters a French word, but due to the processing rules for English, you get hit that wouldn't have happened if you only indexed to the correct field.

By enabling `langid.map`, you can tell Solr to index the content into fields named `fieldname_langcode` (where fieldname is picked up from `langid.fl`).

> `langid.map`: Enables field name mapping. If true, Solr will map field names for all fields listed in `langid.fl`.

You can use `langid.map.replace` or `langid.map.pattern` if you want to change the default `fieldname_langcode` naming, but I'd leave those alone for now.

Comment: Is it possile to use language detection in query ?

Comment: Not that I know of, so you'd probably have to add that to your application. Searching both fields is the usual way to do it (and short queries can limit the trust you can put in the detect language value)

Comment: Currently in solrconfig I have a language detector. In schema.xml, I have two fieldtype (text_en and text_fr). How I set that I want content from english document in content_en and french document in content_fr ?

Comment: Enable `langid.map` - you can see a list of all parameters on the link given in the answer.

Comment: ok thank you it's work. So for a query I should write something like that : `http://localhost:8983/solr/langue/select?q=content_fr:cheval%20OR%20content_en:cheval`

Comment: Correct - I'd prefer using edismax and `qf=content_fr content_en&q=cheval`.